# Check initialized Struct value inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uiview, initialization

I have a `UIView` with a `custom-init` so I can change its `mode`:

```
var wishlistMode: Constants.WishlistMode.Type?

init(wishlistMode: Constants.WishlistMode.Type) {
    self.wishlistMode = wishlistMode
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    setupViews()        
}
```

For that I have created this `struct`:

```
struct Constants: Equatable {

    struct WishlistMode: Equatable {
        static let isCreating = WishlistMode.self
        static let isChanging = WishlistMode.self
    } 

/*...*/

}
```

Inside my `UIView` I have this `function` to check the `WishListMode` but somehow it is always printing out `isChanging`  even if I initialize the `view`  with `let v = CreateNewListView(wishlistMode: Constants.WishlistMode.isCreating)` :

```
func checkWishlistMode(){
    if self.wishlistMode == Constants.WishlistMode.isChanging {
        print("isChanging")
    } else if self.wishlistMode == Constants.WishlistMode.isCreating {
        print("isCreating")
    }
}
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Both isCreating and isChanging has the same value, why? This will always make your first `if` true since `isCreating == isChanging` will always be true.

Comment: oh, I am quite new to structs so what would be the right way to inplement that are two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your struct with constants to an enum instead

```
enum WishlistMode {
    case isCreating
    case isChanging
}
```

and in the UIView code change from `Constants.WishlistMode.Type` to `Constants.WishlistMode`

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thanks :)